# Google Maps JSv3 Freezes for a few seconds every 30 seconds

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, freeze

As per title, does anyone know why it freezes every 30 seconds? 
I figured that it was some sort of timer with Google Maps but cant find any such reference.

To recreate, simply copy into a local file the full html + javascript from:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Open the local html file and then just move the map around and it will freeze within 30 seconds. Once it unfreezes, it works fine until 30 seconds have elapsed.

Seems to only happen in IE (i used version 11). Note that it doesnt freeze within the Google example page above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the [release or frozen versions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), seems like a change in the experimental version.

Comment: I tried 3 and 3.19 and both seem to be fine. However, not specifying the version would result in the freeze, very weird.

Comment: Both 3 and 3.19 give you the release version. Not specifying the version is equivalent to the [experimental version if you read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) (unless you have a business license, then you get the release version by default)

Comment: My apologies, geocodezip. I did read the documentation and i did write a comment to clear up my last comment but did must not have saved it but thats my fault as i am doing a hundred things at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue in the experimental version, currently 3.20.

See [versioning in the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

> **Versioning**
>
> The Google Maps API team will regularly update this Javascript API with new features, bug fixes, and performance improvements. All API changes will be backwards-compatible, ensuring that if you launch an application using the currently documented interfaces, that application will continue to work without modification as the API is updated. (Note: experimental features, documented in the Experimental API Reference are not covered by this guarantee. Features that are experimental will be clearly labeled in the API documentation.)
>
> **Types of Versions**
>
> You can indicate which version of the API to load within your application by specifying it using the v parameter of the Maps Javascript API bootstrap request. Three options are supported:
>
> - The experimental version, specified with v=3.exp.
> - The release version, specified with v=3 or v=3.19.
> - A numbered version, specified with v=3.18.
> - **If you do not explicitly specify a version, you will receive the experimental version by default.** Google Maps API for Work customers who specify a client ID will receive the release version by default.
>
> **The experimental version**
>
> The experimental version — currently 3.20 — contains the latest features and bug fixes as they are made publicly available. Changes made to the experimental version are not guaranteed to be feature stable. We encourage you to regularly test your applications with the experimental version, which you can do by adding v=3.20 when loading the Maps API. If you like to live on the edge, you can add v=3.exp to always receive the current experimental version with all of its latest features.

Comment: Thanks. This pretty much explains it. I had been testing without specifying the version (i originally assumed it would use the release version) and troubleshooting the freezing with the google example which specifies the experimental version.

Comment: Thank you. This fixes my problem of Google Map hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the security settings (for local files).

Because I hosted the exact same file on [github](http://kylelam.github.io/SO/simpleMaps.html), and it seems to work fine. And the only difference between the two files are their storing location. 
If you open the local file, it would says something like `internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or activex controls`, so I would say it is the security settings for local files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks kaho. I will do more tests based on your answer and report back.

Comment: I hosted it in a web server and confirmed that the freezes did stop as you said.

Comment: Thinking that i could trick IE, i tried "Mark of the Web" but no luck. It made the prompt disappear, but the freezing still happens. I will keep this open for a while longer, as i would really like to know the exact cause of the freezing.

Comment: Thanks kaho, i think your suggestion worked around whatever experimental behaviour that was causing the freezing.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run the HTML from a local drive with developer tools on you get the error 'Invalid Argument', in the function below,  then you hit f5 to continue and the map eventually renders.  Hope this helps.

```
function dn(a,b){return a.setQuery=b}function en(a,b){return a.background=b}function fn(a,b){return a.tilt_changed=b}function gn(a,b){return a.bounds_changed=b}function hn(a,b){return a.getStatus=b}function jn(a,b){return a.getQuery=b}function kn(a,b){return a.projectionBounds_changed=b}function ln(a,b){return a.border=b}
```

Comment: The issue here is that it is freezing every 30 seconds with no errors reported on IE (even using the developer console). Thanks anyway.