# Google Maps JS freezes Internet Explorer 11

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, freeze

The example straight from the Google Maps JS docs freezes in IE 11. https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple

If the IE window is small (1/4 of my monitor), it will load with some lag. The larger the window, the more lag it has. When maximized, the browser freezes. Sometimes, it will say there is a long running script and die.

My machine has plenty of resources and I have no issues in other browsers including Edge, Chrome, Firefox. This has been reported by many users. The issue only exists using Google Maps JS with IE 11.

I've tried using different gmap versions, but none have helped yet.

Comment: This may be because of the the experimental version. When you use the Google Maps, you should explicitly specify a versionf. For more, you could refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343055/google-maps-jsv3-freezes-for-a-few-seconds-every-30-seconds

Comment: This issue has reached the engineering team of Google Maps API and are currently working on a fix, you may star this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/123022781) to get future updates on when the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me: setting the version to 3.34 AND setting visibility off to the POI feature, labels element.

Comment: I had tried other versions, mainly 3.31 and it didn't work. 3.34 works. Wow.

Comment: Got the same issue, but seems that 3.34 no longer exists, 3.35 works though.

Comment: @Laure S.  Thanks lots

Answer (score 4):

At the moment there are various problems with IE11 and Google Maps API v3.35:

- map doesn't appear (but it appears once the dev console was open);
- maps gets stuck and take quite a long time to respond;
- script error occurs in Internet Explorer with error messages that resemble the following: *Problems with this Web page might prevent it from being displayed properly or functioning properly...*

The main references in the issue tracker are:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123022781
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115575861

[As suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29343055/3235496) you should specify a version (`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34"></script>`).

The problem seems related to the width of the map: it must be specified in pixels. You cannot let it unspecified (or use a %). So, if you really need the latest features, as  a (not recommended) quick-fix you could calculate in advance the required width.